# map numbers with another number

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an application that has 2 modes: entry mode and return mode

in "entry mode" when a value is entered, it increases pos. and that position is associated with the number entered.

for example, the values ​​are entered and pos = 0:

23

80

67

34

the position will be

23 = 1

80 = 2

67 = 3

34 = 4

if someone enters the value 34 in "return mode" you should return 4

if someone enters the value 23 in "return mode" you should return 1

it's like a number mapping

try using functions
for example for 4 entered values ​​a cubic function is needed

this cubic function associates the values ​​above with the linial numbers

```
y = -16.05735 + 1.1394 * x - 0.01966465 * x ^ 2 + 0.0001030451 * x ^ 3

4 = -16.05735 + 1.1394 * 34 - 0.01966465 * 34 ^ 2 + 0.0001030451 * 34 ^ 3
```

also try to traverse numbers entered in an array called number []

number [0] = 23

number [1] = 80

etc..

```
foo (int number_enter) {
for {int i = 0; i <number.length; i ++) {
if (number_enter == number [i]) {return i;}
}
}

foo (34); // return 4
```

I would like to know if there is a faster way to return associated number for millions of numbers entered.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    void addNumberAtPosition(int number, int position) {
        map.put(number, position);
    }

    int getPositionOfNumber(int number) {
        return map.getOrDefault(number, -1);//return -1 if number is not present.
    }
```